# How to share a record between multiple erl in Erlang?

Tags: erlang, record, erl

I would like to use a -record in every single erl files I have.
I know I can repeat the record individually in every files, but that's really ugly.

Any suggestion ?

P.S. : Be gentle ;-) I'm an Erlang newbie.

Comment: Put it in a .hrl, -include the .hrl

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Put your record definition in a header (.hrl) file. For example, `animal.hrl` may look like:

```
-record(animal, {name, legs=4, eyes=2}).
```

Then in your .erl files you can include the .hrl file like so:

```
-include_lib("animal.hrl").
```

- I'd recommend reading [this](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/a-short-visit-to-common-data-structures#records).
- Note that the .hrl file should probably be placed in your `src` directory unless it's needed outside of your application - in that case you should put it in a directory called `include`.